# Send base64 audio via JSON, how to use in <audio> element?

Tags: html, json, base64

My browser client is receiving JSON with base64 audio as one of its attributes.  How can I use this in my `<audio>` HTML element?

Comment: add token in audio file URL, if token(can contain info of username, Expiration) is Effective, return the audio,  else  return  nil

Comment: @Para so you're saying include security info in the URL itself, like foo.com/<username>/<audiouuid>?  Or is there a way to hide the info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html5 audio tag can play `base64` data directly.
You may send auth audio via json in form of base64 encoded

Then in your html file put it like this

```
<div id="audiodiv" >
    <audio id="audio_player" src="data:audio/mp3;base64,<base64_encoded_audio>"  controls="controls"autobuffer="autobuffer">
     </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the original question to focus only on this aspect of what I was trying to achieve.